# install and enabling vim-youcompleteme on Ubuntu 14.10

Tags: vim

I did follow instructions for installing vim-youcompleteme. 
I searched for similar questions and answers, but still not helping me.

I have clean install of Ubuntu 14.10. Then I installed vim 7.4, vim-youcompleteme and vim-addon-manager. Then run vam install youcompleteme. It was successful.

But, I still dont see the auto completion popup when I edit cpp, or c code.

There is another way of installing youcompleteme using Vundu and doing ./install.sh with parameters, also changes .vimrc.

Since I am using vim-youcompleteme package, I assume these steps already done during installation of vim-youcomplateme package from Ubuntu.

Could someone shed light on this area, please?

Thanks

Comment: On [Github](https://github.com/Valloric/YouCompleteMe) it specifies that when you run `vi --version` you should have `Include patches:1-584` or higher than 584. I'd suggest that you get newer version by building form source. You can refer to the github page that I linked for more info

Comment: Hi Serg,  Thank you for reply. I followed instruction. It said vim 7.3.584 and above. In my case vim version is 7.4

Comment: by the way, I want to use YCM with gcc 4.9. I didn't install clang compiler. is it root of the problem?